# JSF Primefaces validation not working

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

After clicking the submit button, it is not hitting my managed bean, but it is not displaying the validation message either. I feel like this is very simple and do not know why it would not be working.

```
<h:form prependId="false">
  <table class="contactForm">
    <tr>
      <td>Name: </td>
      <td><p:inputText size="20" id="name" value="#{contactManagedBean.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name is required" /></td>
      <td><p:message for="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email: </td>
      <td><p:inputText size="20" id="email" value="#{contactManagedBean.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Email is required" /></td>
      <td><p:message for="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone (###-###-####) (Optional): </td>
      <td><p:inputText size="20" id="phone" maxlength="12" value="#{contactManagedBean.phone}"/></td>
      <td><p:message for="phone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Comments: </td>
      <td><p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" id="comments" value="#{contactManagedBean.comments}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter some comments"></p:inputTextarea></td>
      <td><p:message for="comments" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{contactManagedBean.submitComment()}" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</h:form>
```

Comment: just to note: it's not a good idea to use tables for layout!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add id to h:form and add update attribute to  button.
ex:

```
<h:form id="form">
...
<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="form" actionListener="#{contactManagedBean.submitComment()}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: you can always use `update="@form"` without specifying forms ID, it will rerender the matching form. But it's a good idea to id forms anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that on your commandButton you never have process="@this"